# Can ping but not ssh to server on VPN using ubuntu 22.04 and pulse VPN

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I've just installed a new copy of Ubuntu 22.04, and I need to access a private github repository over a VPN using pulseVPN.

I've created SSH keys and added them to the private github instance.

When I try to clone via ssh I get a timeout error:
ssh connect to host  port 22: Connnection refused.

What I have tried:

- adding the server to .gitconfig
- updating / deleting known hosts
- ssh-add 'ing the ssh keys to make sure they are being used correctly
- pinging/ telnetting to the server, both of which are successful
- ssh'ing to the server: times out

Answer (score 0):

The eventual solution I found was to downgrade pulse vpn to 9.1r14: https://dl.technion.ac.il/docs/cis/public/ssl-vpn/v.9.1R14.0/